# Estimation of a complex quantity from below

Tags: complex-analysis

Is there a positive bound from below, independent of $\lambda$, on the expression

$\frac{1+|\lambda|^2}{2}|z| + \Re(\lambda z)$

where $z$ is a *nonzero* complex number, and $\lambda$ is a complex number such that $|\lambda|<1$?

Here the script $\Re$ is meant to mean the real part of $\lambda z$. I wasn't sure how to type it in the standard notation.

Comment: Try letting $z=x+yi$ and changing your objective function to be all in terms of $x,y,\lambda.$ Then use the two variable method to minimize it, assuming $\lambda$ is a constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

$|\operatorname{re} (\lambda z ) | \le |\lambda | |z|$, hence
${1 \over 2} (1+ |\lambda|^2) |z| + \operatorname{re} (\lambda z ) \ge {1 \over 2} (1+ |\lambda|^2) |z| - |\lambda | |z| = {1 \over 2} (1-|\lambda|)^2 |z|$.

To see why no bound exists, take $z=1$ and $\lambda \in (0,1)$. Then
${1 \over 2} (1+ |\lambda|^2) |z| + \operatorname{re} (\lambda z ) = {1 \over 2} (1-\lambda)^2$, and $\inf_{\lambda \in (0,1)} {1 \over 2} (1-\lambda)^2  = 0$.

Comment: I wonder if this example can be extended past the case when z is precisely 1.